# transactions and logs order

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm building a blockchain game and in order to speed things up, I am also building a web application so users will read data from there.

so at first, I was thinking to listen to events and save their data on my DB, but then I read that the order of the events is not guaranteed, then I thought maybe you use the **transactionIndex** and **logIndex** sort them and then put the data in the database but then I read that the order can also be changed.

is there a way to get events by the order they were mined on the block? the timeline of the data is very important, I cant have it mixed with older events

Comment: What do you mean by "I read that the order of the events is not guaranteed". You can sort them by tx block number

Comment: @AhmadGorji in the block it self. each transaction has  the index in the block and so is the event

Comment: So you want the index of tx in the block too?!

Comment: @AhmadGorji i want to get all the events at the same order they happened in the block, first get transaction order and for each transaction her events in the order the occurred

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know about back-end and database but I guess this might help you. (I am using pure JavaScript and I use Rinkeby testnetwork so addressed are from that blockchain).

The code in JavaScript:

```
const IERC20 = ['function decimals() external view returns (uint8)',
    'function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256)',
    'function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256)',
    'function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)',
    'event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value)',
    'event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value)'
]

const USDCAddress = "0x4DBCdF9B62e891a7cec5A2568C3F4FAF9E8Abe2b";
const YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS;

let provider;
let signer;
let signerAddress;
let YOUR_CONTRACT;
let USDCContract;
let eventTest;

const startFunction = async () => {
    //Connect to metamask
    await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
    //Change network to Rinkeby
    await ethereum.request({ method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain', params:[{chainId: '0x4'}]});
    //Get the provider
    provider = new _ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    //Get signer
    signer = provider.getSigner();
    //Get signer address
    signerAddress = await signer.getAddress();
    //If you use provider instead of signer in function below, you just can't interact with contract.
    USDCContract = await new ethers.Contract(USDCAddress, IERC20, signer);
    USDCContract.on("Approval", (from, to, amount, event) => {
        if (to == contractaddress && from == signerAddress){
            eventTest = event;
            //In console of browser try eventTest and see what it contains and what you look for
           //I think you want these informations:
           event['logIndex'];
           event["blockNumber"];
           await event.getTransactionReceipt(); //This returns transaction of the event
        }
    });
}
startFunction();

async function approve(){
    USDCContract.approve(contractaddress, BigInt("9007199254740990")**3n);
}

//call approve() in browser console and confirm the transaction.
```